# KSQL db - UDF look up a ksqldb table

Tags: apache-kafka, user-defined-functions, ksqldb

Is it possible to create a UDF to receive/look up a ksqldb table?

For example:
Creating UDF which receives Int UserId as a parameter and retrieves from User Table the user name by the received UserId?
I know it can be done by scalar functions with join, but I need to do it by UDF

alternatively, is it possible to receive a ksqldb table row as JSON to UDF (as a parameter)?

Comment: Technically, it's possible if you use Interactive Queries and add an RPC server to your Streams app. But stream-table join is the more optimal way

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks for the reply, by Interactive queries you mean query by REST?

Comment: Not exactly, REST would be an example of the RPC layer mentioned in the documentation. gRPC is another example - https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html